# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x})$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find the limit when $x$ approaches infinity of $\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x}$. I multiplied by the conjugate ($\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x}$) and ended up getting $\frac{x^2 -x +1}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x}}$. Then, I got stuck. How to proceed from here?

Comment: $$\sqrt{x^2+1}>x\gg \sqrt x$$ Did you mean $\sqrt{x+1}$ ?

Comment: No, it's sqrt(xˆ2+1) indeed.

Comment: Then the limit is $\infty$, as can be shown for instance using my reasoning from the first line ($x-\sqrt x$ converges fairly quickly to $\infty$). Your method works too: The numerator behaves asymptotically equivalent to $x^2$ and the denominator is asymptotically equivalent to $x$, so you have convergence to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inutition:  $\sqrt{x^2 + 1} > \sqrt x^2 = x$ and $x\to \infty$ "faster" than $\sqrt{x}\to \infty$ so $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 +1}-\sqrt x)=\infty$.

Formmal definition and proof:

$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ means that for any $M$  the is an $N$ so that $x > N$ means $f(x) > M$.

This is true for $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt x$.

Pf:.  For any $M$ then $N = (M+1)^2$.

Then if $x > N$ then $\sqrt {x^2 + 1} - \sqrt {x}> \sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt x=$

$x - \sqrt x = \sqrt{x}(\sqrt x - 1) >$

$\sqrt{(M+1)^2}( \sqrt {(M+1)^2} - 1) =$

$(M+1)(M+1 -1) = (M+1)M > M$.

That's it.

$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - \sqrt x) = \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2-x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-1+\frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt x}}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $x>M>0$ for some $M\in\Bbb{R}$, $$\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{x^2-x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x}}>\dfrac{x^2-x+1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2}}=\dfrac{x^2-x+1}{2x+1}\xrightarrow{x\to\infty} \infty $$

where the first inequality holds because the denominator $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2}>\sqrt{(x+1)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}>\sqrt{x^2+1}>\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x}\\ \implies \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt{x^2}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Can you please explain the first inequality? why sqrt(x+1)ˆ2 + sqrt(xˆ2) is smaller than the denominator on the left hand side?

Comment: @MiltonLeal Hope it's clearer from the edit now. The denominator on the right hand side of the inequality in line 1 is larger than that on the left hand side.